# Does this class look stupid?

Tags: python

I'm trying to port something I wrote in PHP into Python, mainly as an exercise to better learn the language. The code in question is a SWF parser. In PHP, I have all my data structure declared as classes. I'm trying to do the same in Python but there doesn't seem to be a explicit way to declare a class variable. So I end up with many classes that look like this:

```
class SWFRGBA(object):
    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 0
    alpha = 0
```

Do Pythoners actually write things like this?

**[EDIT]**

Let me post some actual code to illustrate the issue. The function below reads the vector shapes in an SWF file. The readUB(), readSB() reads a certain number of bits interpretating them unsigned or signed. Sometimes, the number of bits required for a given field is itself read from the bitstream. Three types of records might appear: straight edge, quadratic curve, or style change. A style change record might move the pen position, change the line style index, change one of the two fill style indices, or replace the style arrays.

```
protected function readShapeRecords($numFillBits, $numLineBits, $version, &$bytesAvailable) {
    $records = array();
    while($bytesAvailable) {
        if($this->readUB(1, $bytesAvailable)) {
            // edge
            if($this->readUB(1, $bytesAvailable)) {
                // straight
                $line = new SWFStraightEdge;
                $line->numBits = $this->readUB(4, $bytesAvailable) + 2;
                if($this->readUB(1, $bytesAvailable)) {
                    // general line
                    $line->deltaX = $this->readSB($line->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                    $line->deltaY = $this->readSB($line->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                } else {
                    if($this->readUB(1, $bytesAvailable)) {
                        // vertical
                        $line->deltaX = 0;
                        $line->deltaY = $this->readSB($line->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                    } else {
                        // horizontal 
                        $line->deltaX = $this->readSB($line->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                        $line->deltaY = 0;
                    }
                }
                $records[] = $line;
            } else {
                // curve
                $curve = new SWFQuadraticCurve;
                $curve->numBits = $this->readUB(4, $bytesAvailable) + 2;
                $curve->controlDeltaX = $this->readSB($curve->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                $curve->controlDeltaY = $this->readSB($curve->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                $curve->anchorDeltaX = $this->readSB($curve->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                $curve->anchorDeltaY = $this->readSB($curve->numBits, $bytesAvailable);
                $records[] = $curve;
            }
        } else {
            $flags = $this->readUB(5, $bytesAvailable);
            if(!$flags) {
                break;
            } else {
                // style change
                $change = new SWFStyleChange;
                if($flags & 0x01) {
                    $change->numMoveBits = $this->readSB(5, $bytesAvailable);
                    $change->moveDeltaX = $this->readSB($change->numMoveBits, $bytesAvailable);
                    $change->moveDeltaY = $this->readSB($change->numMoveBits, $bytesAvailable);
                }
                if($flags & 0x02) {
                    $change->fillStyle0 = $this->readUB($numFillBits, $bytesAvailable);
                }
                if($flags & 0x04) {
                    $change->fillStyle1 = $this->readUB($numFillBits, $bytesAvailable);
                }
                if($flags & 0x08) {
                    $change->lineStyle = $this->readUB($numLineBits, $bytesAvailable);
                }
                if($flags & 0x10) {
                    $change->newFillStyles = $this->readFillStyles($version, $bytesAvailable);
                    $change->newLineStyles = $this->readLineStyles($version, $bytesAvailable);
                    $change->numFillBits = $numFillBits = $this->readUB(4, $bytesAvailable);
                    $change->numLineBits = $numLineBits = $this->readUB(4, $bytesAvailable);
                }
                $records[] = $change;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->alignToByte();
    return $records;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and what casing style should I use for instance variables? My code in PHP uses CamcelCase.

Comment: Those _are_ explicit class variables, but are  you sure that is what you want?

Comment: For Python naming conventions, see the [naming section of the PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

Comment: @cleong: for coding style related issues, consult PEP8. For instance variables, you'd usually use lowercase separated by underscore

Comment: If you try to port PHP constructs and methods into Python you're giving yourself a horrible introduction. If you implement the high-level functional behavior of your code, you'll get something not horrible but it will be harder.

Comment: How can we edit this question? Right now this amounts to someone asking for their code to be checked. namedtuples certainly doesn't answer the question: "Does this Python class look stupid?" No one has answered that yet.

Comment: I can edit it, but I can't figure how to cast it into a good question which is why I commented and voted to close it as "not a real question".

Comment: @gnibbler Are explicit class variables commonly used by Python programmers? I know you can do it, but does it make me look like a noob, that's sort of the question. It's more a cultural question.

Comment: @cleong, class variables have a place, but I would not say they are commonly used. Can you give some more details/code in the question? I don't think anyone has understood what you are asking for yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid a class like that would look kind of dumb to anyone who knew Python well.

A *real* Pythonista might use a metaclass to parameterize the making of the sort of classes you want. A metaclass is just a class whose instances are other classes. Here's an example of one that does many of the things I think you want (from your question and comments):

```
from copy import copy

class MetaStruct(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, cls_dict):
        try:
            fields = cls_dict['fields']
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError("No 'fields' attribute defined in class " + `name`)

        # field names may be separated by whitespace and/or commas
        fields = fields.replace(',', ' ').split()
        del cls_dict['fields']  # keep out of class instances

        if 'default_field_value' not in cls_dict:
            default_field_value = None  # default default field value
        else:
            default_field_value = cls_dict['default_field_value']
            del cls_dict['default_field_value']   # keep out of class instances

        super(MetaStruct, cls).__init__(name, bases, cls_dict)

        def __init__(self, **kwds):
            """ __init__() for class %s """ % name
            self.__dict__.update(zip(fields, [copy(default_field_value)
                                                  for _ in xrange(len(fields))]))
            self.__dict__.update(**kwds)

        def __setattr__(self, field, value):
            """ Prevents new field names from being added after creation. """
            if field in self.__dict__:
                self.__dict__[field] = value  # avoid recursion!
            else:
                raise AttributeError('Can not add field %r to instance of %r' %
                                     (field, name))
        # add defined methods to class instance
        setattr(cls, '__init__', __init__)
        setattr(cls, '__setattr__', __setattr__)
```

With the metaclass defined as shown, you can then use it to declare different classes and then create one or more instances of them. In Python memory is mostly managed for you, so there is no `new` operator like PHP apparently requires. As a result of that, there are no pointers, so access to class members is generally done through dot notation rather than `->`.

With that said, here's an example of declaring a struct-like class, creating a couple of separate instances of it, and accessing their members:

```
# sample usage
class SWF_RGBA(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaStruct
    fields = 'red, green, blue, alpha'
    default_field_value = 0  # otherwise would be None

c1 = SWF_RGBA()
print vars(c1)  # {'blue': 0, 'alpha': 0, 'green': 0, 'red': 0}
c2 = SWF_RGBA(red=1, blue=4)
print vars(c2)  # {'blue': 4, 'green': 0, 'alpha': 0, 'red': 1}
```

You can assign values to as many or few of the class's fields as you wish in the constructor call by using keyword arguments, which can be given in any order. Unassigned fields are given a default value of `None`. Fields may be of any type.

Any existing field of instances of the class created can be referred to using dot notation:

```
print c2.blue  # 4
c2.green = 3  # assign a new value to existing green attribute
```

But new fields cannot be added after an instance is created:

```
c2.bogus = 42  # AttributeError: Can not add field 'bogus' to instance of 'SWF_RGBA'
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the answer I'm looking for. I can write stuff in Python, but I always suspect that my code looks clearly like what a C programmer struggling with Python would produce.

Comment: @cleong: You're welcome. Nothing wrong with being a C programmer learning Python -- just wish I had something like Stack Overflow when I was trying to get up to speed. Regardless, it can be kind of fun.

Comment: martineau, Because you could see what was being asked, can you say we have a question that can be edited to meet S.O. standards? If yes, please consider another contribution by editing the question.

Comment: @Honest Abe: Even though the OP accepted my answer and said it was what they were looking for, I was only guessing at what they wanted based on additional information they provided in comments, especially to Pambo Paschalides's answer. In my opinion if anyone should edit the question -- which is dangerously close to being closed -- to make it more clear, it should be the asker, not a third party like myself.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want instances that hold a bunch of attributes, you should use [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Comment: Aren't tuples immutable? The ultimate purpose of parsing the SWF is to modify it. The records will be changed so I don't think this would work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you mean by saying:

> but there doesn't seem to be a explicit way to declare a class variable

Your code snippet defines a class with 4 class variables.

Yes there are cases where Python programmers write classes like that. But this, at least in my view, is more like a grouping of related data, than a class which will produce objects.

As far as the case is concerned, traditionally it's lowercase for variables, and uppercase for constants(technically there are no constants in Python, but that's another discussion). For example:

```
attempts = 5
attempts_on_target = 2
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on the casing. I just want to make sure before I started editing everything.

Comment: Basically, I just need a bunch of containers that hold some values, more or less like a C struct. Often times many members will be omitted. Initializing the members in the constructor is sort of awkward.

Comment: Let me try to explain the issue a bit better. SWF employs a lot of data structures. They're all documented in one large PDF file. Looking them up in the PDF file is not very convenient. So detailing what each structure can contain is helpful. Since Flash tries to keep its files small, often times many members of a data structure would be omitted. I handle this in PHP simply by not assigned the instance variable. Since declared variables in PHP have the initial values of NULL, I can easily tell whether some members weren't set. Should I create a bunch of classes with members all set to None?

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where class variable is desirable, but I believe this is not that. Most of the member variables you need are usually going to be instance variables, that is declared by assigning them a value in the **init** method.